# Canonical QTranslator example with real-world QLocale

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization, qtranslator

It seems that most documentation on `QTranslator` and installing them for a `QApplication` assume [simplistic cases](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html#details) for `QLocale`.

In the real-world the locale of the user must take into account language and country, which is commonly achieved by having translation files first for a language (`en`) and then additional translation files for each country using that language (`en_US`).

Using the default `QLocale()`, what is the most elegant way to load the appropriate translation files (one, two or none, depending on which exist)?

Here [some code](https://gitlab.savoirfairelinux.com/ring/ring-client-gnome/commit/884ef73e9276dfc26452c5b0945f57a55d663adb?view=parallel&w=1) that get's it right, but is a bit too cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Application::installTranslator(QString localeName)
{
  QTranslator* translator = new QTranslator(this);

  QString fileToLoad = ":/translators/translation_" + localeName + ".qm";

  if (!QFile::exists(fileToLoad))
    return;

  if (translator->load(fileToLoad)) // Caution this will perform stripping of '_' heuristic
    QApplication::installTranslator(translator);
}

void Application::installTranslator()
{
  QLocale locale;
  boost::optional<QString> optLanguage = m_commandLineParser->getLanguage();
  if (optLanguage)
    locale = QLocale(optLanguage.get());

  // Load language (en, de, etc.) translator first
  QString language = locale.name().left(2);
  installTranslator(language);

  // Load country translator (en_US, de_CH, etc.) translator second
  installTranslator(locale.name());
}
```